# Drawing the national flag of France

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'am trying to draw the national flag of France in PyQt5.

[image]

After looking around I found about gradients but after playing a bit with them it doesn't seem like that's what I need. I can get the colors right and in the right direction but they don't become solid all the way to the stop points, like they do in the flag. This is what I tried:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QWidget)

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.square = QFrame(self)
        self.square.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 400)

        self.square.setStyleSheet("QFrame {background: qlineargradient( x1:0 y1:0, x2:1 y2: 0, stop:0 blue, stop: 0.33 white, stop:0.66 red);}}")

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What do I need in order to successfully be able to draw this flag?

Comment: A gradient is not what you need. Did you try to draw three rectangles inside the QFrame?

Comment: @LutzHorn I just thought of that and it does work. What you mean by drawing three rectangles inside the QFrame? I used one QFrame as the container and then put three other QFrames inside, one for each color. Should I use another class for to draw each rectangle or is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: No, that sounds good.

Comment: You should re-implement the paintEvent and draw the rectangles and gradients inside it (no stylesheets or unnecessary QFrames just to draw stuff). Do you know how to do this (re-implement the paintEvent)?

Comment: @armatita I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ok. I've added a small example as answer. Check if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version with a re-implementation of the `paintEvent`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class FlagWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FlagWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        s = self.size()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)

        # Using antialiasing (this shape is simple so you can set it to False)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)

        # Here I'm saying that no border should exist in the rectangles
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)

        # Setting the brush (color or gradient for each rectangle)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("blue"))
        # Drawing the rectangle with arguments coordinate X, Y, size X, Y
        qp.drawRect(0, 0, int(s.width()/3), s.height())
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("white"))
        qp.drawRect(int(s.width()/3), 0, int(s.width()/3), s.height())
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("red"))
        qp.drawRect(int(s.width()/3)*2, 0, int(s.width()/3), s.height())

        qp.end()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = FlagWidget()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This results in the following:

[image: QWidget as a flag of France]

Notice that the size of a window might not be perfectly divisible by 3 so you may have 2 or 3 empty pixels at the end.

To solve this empty space problem you can prolong the last stripe using something like this in the drawing of the last rectangle:

```
qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("red"))
qp.drawRect(int(s.width()/3)*2, 0, s.width() - int(s.width()/3)*2, s.height())
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I had looked at QPainter before but I had gotten the impression it would only work with the Graphics View framework and not with QWidget.